# Backwards BroadcastReceiver Senders

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I have goofed something up here with my Broadcast Receivers and my Sender.  perhaps another set of eyes would be useful.

I have my lightsensor which is supposed to broadcast changes to the receiving activity.

Here is the LightSensor.java

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    lightLux = event.values[0]; //Final output of this sensor.
    Lux = String.valueOf(lightLux);
    sendLuxUpdate();

    Log.d("LightSensor", Lux);
    TextView tvLightSensorLux = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLightSensorLux);
    tvLightSensorLux.setText(Lux);
}

private void sendLuxUpdate() {
      Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
      Intent intent = new Intent("LuxUpdate");
      // You can also include some extra data.
      intent.putExtra("Lux", lightLux);
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Then my Record.java is suposed to receive those updates to the lux:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);


    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mLightReceiver,
              new IntentFilter("LuxUpdate"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mLightReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String lux = intent.getStringExtra("Lux");
    Log.d("Light Lux", "Lux Update: " + lux);
    TextView tvSensorLightLux = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSensorLightLux);
    tvSensorLightLux.setText(lux);
}
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mLightReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

I think it is just a matter of the sending and receiving id, but am not totally sure.  Once the Record activity receives the broadcast, it should update the TextView tvSensorLightLux or at least Log.d the Lux value from LightSensor.java

Comment: in `intent.putExtra("Lux", lightLux);` is `lightLux` is string ?

Comment: No in that instance it is a float. Is that bad?

Comment: in your receiver `String lux = intent.getStringExtra("Lux");` requires name "Lux" should have value to be String. and as you have said you are passing instance of float

Comment: you are right.  Can I pass a float instead?

Comment: Also, best I can tell either the receiver is not receiving or the sender is not broadcasting

Comment: yes you can pass Float. Just In receiver add `String lux =intent.getFloatExtra("Lux", defaultValue);` put default value you want, say `0`

Comment: ok I got it.  How do I give you credit for the help?

Comment: I posted it as answer, Accept it as it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing Float and in receiver you are using,

```
String lux = intent.getStringExtra("Lux");
```

which requires `"Lux"` to be String.

As you are passing Float. In receiver Just add `getFloatExtra()`

```
lux =intent.getFloatExtra("Lux", defaultValue);
```

put default value you want, say `0`